# Exception - bounds of array checking is amiss?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, exception, bounds

Any clue as to why the line indicated below would be throwing an exception?

```
-(double)calibrationValueAtIndex:(int)index
{
    NSLog(@"count: %d   index: %d",[theTopValues count], index);
    return [[theTopValues objectAtIndex:index] doubleValue];  // exception happening here
}

2012-07-23 21:51:16.448 TestAppTimerAndHits[15130:f803] count: 9   index: 7
2012-07-23 21:51:22.339 TestAppTimerAndHits[15130:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSOrderedSetM objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
```

how can it NSLog a count of 9 in the line prior, then report in the exception that the bounds are `[0 .. 4]`?

The exception seems to get thrown 'randomly'.. in some cases, the array bounds are fine, meaning I can get object at index 8... but other times, it will report the bounds as low as `[0 .. 2]`?

In view controller (only VC one in the project)

theBufferManager = [[HitBufferManager alloc] init];

in .h file:
@property NSMutableOrderedSet* theTopValues;

in .m file:
@synthesize theTopValues;

-(id)init for HitBufferManager:
theTopValues = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithCapacity:numToStore];  // returns an autoreleased version.

The individual items are added/edited:

```
        [self sortTopValues];

        if([theTopValues count]<numToStore)
        {
            [theTopValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:windowVal]];
        }
        else if(logVal> [[theTopValues objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue])
        {
            [theTopValues replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:logVal]];
        }
```

Comment: This is not a fragment of a multi-threaded program, is it?

Comment: I was wondering that... and wondering if I've done something wrong with memory management.  I'm guessing that for some reason the elements in the array are being garbage collected?  it is an iOS/iPhone app, and I've done nothing intentional to make it multi-threaded, but it is my first app, so I may not be aware that it is trying to multi-thread something anyway?

Comment: If it's for iOS, there's no GC, only ref counting. You may have a dangling reference, though. Do you use ARC?

Comment: @user1405352: GC is certainly not the problem (and you'd have to have turned it on explicitly). Are you using a dispatch queue anywhere?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes.. at least I think so.. if i enter NSString* dummy = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease]; I get an error forbidding autorelease.

Comment: If you log theTopValues does it give you what you expect?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - no dispatch queues, or usage of GCD.

Comment: Turned on Zombies to track your object deallocation?

Comment: @rdelmar - theTopValues is the NSMutableOrderedSet causing the grief.. log it like how?  by iterating over each of the elements?  I suspect if I did that, i'd run into the same issue when accessing the element once it goes out of the bounds

Comment: ah ha... perhaps a clue.. this time, when running, I see2012-07-23 22:44:58.472 TestAppTimerAndHits[15420:f803] count: 9   index: 2
objc[15420]: Object 0x684c1e0 of class __NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
2012-07-23 22:45:10.064 TestAppTimerAndHits[15420:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSOrderedSetM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: You don't need to iterate, just NSLog(@"%@",theTopValues) should print out the values.  It looks like you do have ARC turned on (it's the default), but it could still be a dangling reference as dasblinkenlight said.  How do you declare theTopValues?

Comment: @rdelmar - see edits to the original post that shows the code where I modify theTopValues

Comment: @rdelmar - yes, I do get the expected values:  2012-07-23 23:08:32.507 TestAppTimerAndHits[15541:f803] count: 9   index: 4
2012-07-23 23:08:32.508 TestAppTimerAndHits[15541:f803] {(
    9.123073426757015,
    9.149688348517669,
    9.256015780291216,
    9.345160846662834,
    9.410557568497204,
    9.532735539969627,
    9.760611212931289,
    9.786390422418268,
    9.800151465666232
)}  NSLog output is just fine.. then the next call to getObjectAtIndex throws the exception

Comment: I don't think this will make a difference, but since you declared theTopValues as a property you really should access it with self.theTopValues

Comment: @rdelmar - nope, didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a multi-thread problem.  In main.m I have @autoreleasepool{}.  However, in my debug output I'm getting all these messages about objc[16165]: Object 0x682ec20 of class __NSOrderedSetM autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug.  I am using a call to AudioOutputUnitStart and in the AURenderCallbackStruct is where I am modifying theTopValues... then, in the view controller's updateDisplay is where the out of bounds exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing :in .h file: @property NSMutableOrderedSet* theTopValues;

to in .h file: @property (strong) NSMutableOrderedSet* theTopValues;

See if that fixes it.

Comment: but... makes me wonder why it is reporting : __NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a multi-threading problem.  A well placed @synchronized{} around the bit of code where I was sorting and modifying the NSOrderedSet seemed to clean up the problem in the portion where I was reading it back.  My problem now is trying to figure out where my other thread is coming from.  Is it

```
CADisplayLink* gameTimer;
gameTimer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self
                                        selector:@selector(updateDisplay:)];

[gameTimer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

and/or does this start a thread?

```
 AudioUnitSetProperty(_effectState.rioUnit,
                      kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                      kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                      bus0, 
                      &callbackStruct, 
                      sizeof(callbackStruct);
 AudioOutputUnitStart(_effectState.rioUnit);
```

Comment: The callback on your AudioUnit may be called in a background thread. Just set a breakpoint in your callback and inspect which thread it's running on, you will know for sure :)